# cxf jar with latest xjc version 2.2.6 needed

Tags: maven, ant, jaxb, jaxb2

Can any one please post me where to find a cxf jar which has the latest  xjc version in. Currently I am using 2.2.11 and it throws an erorr when using with -xjc-Xannotate. can u also tell me how can we look into cxf jar and tell it has the latest xjc version in it?

Answer (score 0):

xjc is an official component of [Oracle/Sun Java Development Kit](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html#bnbal).

Inside Apache CXF distribution, you have xjc libraries for internal use. You better use JDK xjc.

To know which version of xjc is in cxf, just check the file in lib directory, for example, the latest cxf version (2.6.1) shows a xjc version of 2.2.5 :

```
apache-cxf-2.6.1/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar
```

You can have the latest version of xjc in the [JAXB RI](http://jaxb.java.net). Currently, the latest version is 2.2.6.